# Why are bounty points lost along with a question when it is deleted?

Tags: support, bounty

Today I lost **-100** reputation on Stack Overflow.

When I check the reputation tab, all I can see that, a bounty question which I answered at least a month ago and awarded **+100** reputation for this answer is deleted *6 hours* ago.

I also checked the https://stackoverflow.com/reputation page, but I couldn't find any other information.

To be honest, I don't even remember what was the question is about. All I can see is its title right now, and it is not linked to the question any more.

**My question is;**

*Is it fair to **delete** earned bounty points along with removed questions?*

Because, what I understand from bounty questions is; someone is paying for promoting their question and hopes for the attention of possible answerers. If this question is **deleted** or **removed** months later for some reason; why we are *punishing* the answerer who gave his/her time and experience to answer this question?

Comment: Your beef is with the SO user that asked the question (Rich Bailo), he deleted his question 6 hours ago.  Which he could do because nobody voted for your answer.  When you have to write "Giving a good answer ...is not possible" then you ought to consider whether there is any point in wasting your free time on a question like that.  There isn't.

Comment: I can kind of see your point. It seems counter-intuitive that *bounty* rep is lost along with the question when the question gets deleted.  The big question is why that question got deleted, though - I don't think that's typical to questions that have had a bounty. Can you post the question's title so we can take a look?

Comment: Title of the question is: "MVC 5 Identity Users belong to user". It was weeks ago, I don't remember the question and I don't have enough reputation to see deleted questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37537752/3001761, for those with 10k+ rep. Your answer was not worth 100 rep, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731 for why

Comment: IMHO your answer should have been a comment as you did not answer the problem but instead gave the user references.  That question should have been closed, not answered.

Comment: So theoretically speaking, the bounty would come back if the question is undeleted? Asking out of curiosity here since I can't see this specific question.